# Python how to find data under a pre tag

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, frames

I would like use Python to get some data under a pre tag from an html page.

[The html looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSk5k.png)

I tried to use Selenium first but it fails to find the element by xpath.

```
browser = webdriver.Ie()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
browser.get('file:\\\my_url.html')
body= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/pre[2]")))
print(body.text)
```

I tried to use bs4. However, BeautifulSoup keeps telling me that my browser does not support Frames extension. I am not familiar with bs4 and cannot find any useful solution. Can anyone tell me how to modify the setting of IE browser to successfully read the data? Thanks!

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import html2text

url = " " #this html page is on a network drive and can be opened by IE\Chrome\...
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

text = soup.get_text()
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print(text)

>>>This page is designed to be viewed by a browser which supports Frames extension. 
This text will be shown by browsers which do not support the Frames extension.
```

Comment: which pages are you trying to get data from. Atleast provide the html structure of the page.

Comment: There are many sections of data stored under a frameset.

Comment: no images please. SO is about code, your document is useless here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pre` element is inside a `<frame>` with the name "glhstry_main", so you need to switch to it first, before accessing your element. Here:

```
browser = webdriver.Ie()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
browser.get('file:\\\my_url.html')
browser.switch_to_frame("glhstry_main")  // switching to the frame
body= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/pre[2]")))
print(body.text)
//do your frame stuff
driver.switch_to.default_content()     // switching back to original HTML from the frame
```